# Aggregate values in multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

From start I have a list of orders in the following way:

```
                (
                    [product_id] => 1094
                    [total_weight] => 0.0390
                    [qty_ordered] => 10.0000
                    [category_id] => 12
                )
```

What I want is to sum the values for *total_weight* and *qty_ordered* based on *category_id*

I have managed to get the array in the below manner now using a foreach. But I need to aggregate the values somehow.

```
Array
(
    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 1099
                    [total_weight] => 0.0390
                    [qty_ordered] => 10.0000
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 1095
                    [total_weight] => 0.0395
                    [qty_ordered] => 10.0000
                )
        )
    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 1094
                    [total_weight] => 0.0390
                    [qty_ordered] => 10.0000
                )
        )
    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 742
                    [total_weight] => 0.1250
                    [qty_ordered] => 1.0000
                )
        )
)
```

So ideally I would the output to be like with below with as little code as possible:

```
Array
(
    [14] => Array
        (
            [total_weight] => 0.0785
            [qty_ordered] => 20.0000
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [total_weight] => 0.0390
            [qty_ordered] => 10.0000
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [total_weight] => 0.1250
            [qty_ordered] => 1.0000
        )
)
```

Comment: You forgot to post your current code

Answer (score 1):

I was able to sort it in the below way.

```
    foreach($retval as $val) {
        $return[$val['category_id']]['qty_ordered'] += $val['qty_ordered'];
        $return[$val['category_id']]['row_total'] += $val['row_total'];
    }
```